# Why does a perforated plate with small holes prevents high frequency noise?

Tags: waves, acoustics

Beside the reason of high frequency wave having short wavelength and there is no diffraction is there another reason why mesh or acoustic grid prevent high frequency noise from getting into microphone?

BR

Comment: Are you talking about a [pop filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop_filter)?

Comment: It was not basically that but i guess they have the same principle, I was implying on simple holes like that in laptop or smart phones

Comment: I guess windscreen use the principle of blocking high frequency wave but i am not certain

Comment: A pop screen **does not** act as a high frequency filter. What it does is stop the air currents from the speaker's breath reaching the microphone. Those air currents can generate high frequency noise if they flow over the microphone. So the pop screen does prevent high frequency noise, but not by acting as a frequency filter.

Comment: Oh ok and does windscreen act like a frequency filter?

Comment: No, it doesn't. A material like cloth can act as a frequency filter because it absorbs high frequencies i.e. turns the sound energy in the air into heat in the cloth.

Comment: What if we replace the cloth here with a metal but with same amount of holes?.  will this turn result into frequency filter

Answer (score 0):

To sum up and elaborate John Rennie's very good hints:

You are mixing two different mechanisms. The airflow blocking prevents vortical flow incidence at the microphone. That is desirable because the vortex shedding at the microphone causes broadband noise. See the aeroacoustics and vortex sound theory for more reference (e.g. Howe: Theory of Vortex Sound).

The second mentioned mechanism is a model of acoustic flows through a thin hole. "Thin" means that the boundary layer occupies the whole hole cross-section. In this limit the wave equation collapses to a diffusion equation: the sound is attenuated and its phase velocity is significantly reduced. The attenuation coefficient is frequency dependent. See any basic acoustics of viscothermal fluids for the whole derivation (e.g. Pierce, chapter 10).

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation, so for the air travelling through the hole (like in second case) the attenuation coeffecient depends on the size and number of the holes and it is not a constant resistance throught the whole frequency range.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to think ybout it.